# MS Access to MySQL Linked Table via ODBC >> Is there any way to decrypt columns

Tags: mysql, ms-access, encryption

I have a MS Access Frontend to a MySQL DB via a linked table this was working well but  recently implemented MySQL encryption for a new security concern.

Do you  know any way to decrypt the Fields using the Linked table interface?

Comment: Is MySQL encryption a new feature? Perhaps an updated ODBC driver would give you what's needed? Otherwise, I don't know if there's any workaround, unless MySQL is using a standard encryption method and you know the relevant key.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would to create a view on MySQL. This view could have AES_DECRYPT in Select. This way Access would see decrypted data.